# UT61E multimeter AC Voltage measurement issue

Tags: multimeter

when i connect to AC 220V it start at 99 acv and drop to 70 or 60 which is wrong value for that AC..how can i fix this issue?
i cleaned VR2 with some alcohol, rotate it, the voltage changed to +350 ACV for couple of second then back to the same issue again
i replaced VR2 still same issue.
i found that D6 and D5 are shorted, took them out of circuit and they were fine. tested where they been soldered to and it's shorted . i have an old multimeter same that have faulty controller. anyway i found the same diodes shorted in it as well.
[image]

Comment: Is this the same problem from ten years ago? [UT61E multimeter AC measurement issue](https://maker.pro/forums/threads/ut61e-multimeter-ac-measurement-issue.300100/)

Comment: @AndrewMorton and from a user with the same username o.O

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the multimeter gives wrong read for 220 AC Voltage, it read it as 70 ACV
@AndrewMorton it wasn't ten years ago. it was in Jan 2, 2024

Comment: @pharaon Oops, sorry, my mistake for confusing the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the selector switch as the culprit. By a long shot.

And then (maybe) one of the many electrolytic capacitors around U2.

D5 and D6 clearly cannot be checked in-circuit because they have a 9Ω resistor in parallel.

As you've been fiddling with the calibration adjustments, you might consider a new meter at some point soon unless you have access to the tools to recalibrate the meter.

Comment: i have cleaned the selector switch before with alcohol and nothing happen.
also do you mean U1 not U2?

Comment: U2 is the RMS-to-DC converter so it's uniquely involved in AC measurements.

Comment: and how can i test U2 for malfunction? i include links for the board pictures
https://ibb.co/86H8Rzj - https://ibb.co/86H8Rzj

Comment: U2 is an expensive part. If it is gone, a new meter would likely be indicated. I suggest looking at "one of the many electrolytic capacitors around U2".

Comment: i've checked all capacitors around U2 with two multimeters, on this side of the board https://ibb.co/86H8Rzj and no shorted capacitors..i've also cleaned selector switch and it's tracks with alcohol, but still same issue give me read of 70 ACV as measurement for 220 ACV